# Can't boot Windows 7 after installing Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-7

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit yesterday and now I can't boot my Windows 7. What can I do now ?

Comment: Try [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Comment: There is few information in your question so it is hard to give you and answer. Please edit your question by adding additional information. Did you keep your windows partition? Are you seeing an option to boot Windows 7 when you start your computer up?

Comment: is option there for windows 7 at the boot loader?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)